# Advanced join for an Ansible use case

Tags: ansible

I have the following pool configuration in Ansible:

```
_pool_config: "{{ (environment_hosts | default(['localhost'])) | join(':2100,') }}:2100{% if ssl_enabled | bool %},sslSettings=TLS{% endif %}"
```

Which on the server resolves to that:

```
server1:2100,server2:2100
```

I am now adding an additional process on server1 and server2 listening on port 2200 so would like to change the above to resolve to this instead:

server1:2100,server1:2200,server2:2100,server2:2200

And need some help amending the join please

I'm using Ansible 2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more options:

- Use filter [*product*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products)

```yaml
    env_hosts: [server1, server2]
    env_ports: [2100, 2200]
    _pool_config: "{{ env_hosts|default(['localhost'])|
                      product(env_ports)|
                      map('join', ':')|
                      join(',') }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
_pool_config: server1:2100,server1:2200,server2:2100,server2:2200
```

---

- The Jinja template below gives the same result

```yaml
    env_hosts: [server1, server2]
    env_ports: [2100, 2200]
    _pool_config: |-
      {% for server in  env_hosts|default(['localhost']) %}
      {% for port in  env_ports %}
      {{ server }}:{{ port }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
      {%- endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

---

- You can write a filter on your own. For example,

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/my_product.py
from itertools import product


def my_product(x, y):
    return product(x, y)


class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'my_product': my_product,
        }
```

Then, use the filter *my_product*

```yaml
    env_hosts: [server1, server2]
    env_ports: [2100, 2200]
    _pool_config: "{{ env_hosts|default(['localhost'])|
                      my_product(env_ports)|
                      map('join', ':')|
                      join(',') }}"
```

Comment: Seems to be getting this on my side: "template error while templating string: no filter named 'product'" ?

Here are my lines:

_env_ports: [2100, 2200]

_pool_config: "{{ env_hosts | default(['localhost'])| product(_env_ports)| map('join', ':')| join(',') }}{% if _ssl_enabled | bool %},sslSettings=TLS{% endif %}"

Worth adding this gets fed into j2 template

Comment: Also worth adding i'm using old Ansible 2.3 still...

Comment: Does this mean there's no possibly way of doing this in 2.3 ? I'll accept any hack :)

Comment: No way generating such String outside Jinja ? :-/

Comment: Thanks. Not that advanced yet I'm afraid... :(

Comment: Wouldn't that work ? _pool_config: "{{ (env_hosts | default(['localhost'])) | join(':2100,') }}:2100,{{ (env_hosts | default(['localhost'])) | join(':2200,') }}:2200{% if _ssl_enabled | bool %},sslSettings=TLS{% endif %}"

Comment: Thank you. The above from myself also works however I accepted your solution as well. Thank you so much for taking the time to help !